# Pass drop down list value to jquery in Grails

Tags: jquery, html, grails, drop-down-menu

I'm revamping a registration form, and am looking to use jQuery to simplify the form.

Users to the site can be either `Teachers`, `Donors` or both.  `Teachers` have fields that `Donors` don't need, and vice versa.  So, rather than stuffing a form with all the fields and confusing international users by asking their teaching grade level, I've implemented a drop down list so that the user can select their role and the unique required fields come into view via the `append()` method.

This is the form I've built thus far:

```
<g:formRemote name="register" url="[controller:'user', action:'register']" onSuccess="showFields()">
    <dl>
        <dt>User name</dt>
        <dd><g:textField name="username" value ="${user?.username }"/></dd>

        <dt>Password</dt>
        <dd><g:passwordField name="password" value = "${user?.password }"/></dd>

        <dt>Repeat Password</dt>
        <dd><g:passwordField name="passwordRepeat" value = "${user?.passwordRepeat }" /></dd>

        <dt>Account Type</dt>
        <dd>
            <g:select name="role" from="${['Teacher', 'Donor', 'Both'] }"/>
        </dd>
    </dl>



    <input type="submit" value="Register" />
</g:formRemote>
```

and the script is

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#role').change(function(){
        var user = $('#role option:selected').text();

        alert(user);

        if (user == 'Teacher'){

        } else if (user == 'Donor'){

        } else {

        }

    });
</script>
```

Using firebug, I've verified that the select list has the id `role`, but the function is not firing off.  In fact, its completely ignored, no matter what selection I make.

Why is this happening?

Comment: Is the script inside $(document).ready?

Comment: @SimonEdström, your suggestion was the solution.  If you submit it as an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: Thank you, I posted an answer. It is maybe basic for you, but I tried to explain so other can understand whats happening...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the script is executed Before the DOM has loaded. So when you trying to bind the eventhandler the element don't exist.

So what you have to do is to wrap the complete function inside the document ready event, which will try to bind the change eventhandler after the complete DOM have been loaded.

```
$(document).ready(function (){
    $('#role').change(function(){
        var user = $('#role option:selected').text();

        alert(user);

        if (user == 'Teacher'){

        } else if (user == 'Donor'){

        } else {

        }
    });
});
```

Or you can simply add the script at bottom of your page. It's not recommended but FYI...

Answer (score 1):

You need to do:

```
$("[name='role']").change(function () {
```

You are selecting on an id property using `#name`, using the above code you're selecting elements that have the name attribute of role.

Comment: @Jason say that he have checked firebug and the *id* is role.

Comment: Yeah, but from the markup it isn't :). I suspect he may be confusing what he's seeing in Firebug :)

Comment: The problem was I didn't have the function inside $(document).ready.  So it wasn't being called since there was no explicit function call on change.

Comment: Ah okay, totally overlooked that :)